# Twilio record meeting

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-video

How to get a correct video room record from Twilio. I'm using C# SDK

Creating room:
`var room = await RoomResource.CreateAsync(null, RoomResource.RoomTypeEnum.GroupSmall, name, recordParticipantsOnConnect: true);`

Then I have room sid in database. And I want to get record of meeting. I found in documentation link for recordings `https://video.twilio.com/v1/Rooms/{RoomSId}/Recordings`. But how to get that from C# SDK I don't want to parse it manually.

And second. I need to allow user to watch meeting record. I don't need to separate record for each parcipiants and tracks. Is there a simple way how to get one video for meeting?

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/recordings-resource

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I saw that docs. But where should I found RecordingSid? And also it's not easy to connect all recordings to one video. I need something like Teams meeting recording

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/recordings-resource#recordings-list-resource

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Twilio documentation normally has examples in your SDK of choice. For example, if you have a room SID you can [retrieve the recordings for a room](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/recordings-resource?code-sample=code-get-all-recordings-from-a-given-room&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=5.x) with the following:

```cs
TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

var groupingSid = new List<string> {
  ROOM_SID
};

var recordings = RecordingResource.Read(groupingSid: groupingSid, limit: 20);
```

There are recordings per-participant in a room as these are just the raw recordings. If you want a single video that can be watched by someone else, you will need to either stitch the recordings together or you can use the [Twilio Video Compositions API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/compositions-resource). Check out the [Compositions API documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/compositions-resource) for all the details on how to create a single viewable video.